# Making a translator dictionary with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, applet

So, I have an assignment for class that I just have no idea where to start. We're suppose to make a small (like 10 words) English to some other language dictionary that also displays pictures related to the word.

The applet is suppose to have one text field, where you enter a word in either language, click the corresponding translation button (so English button if you typed a word in the other language and Other Language button if you typed the word in english) which will then translate the word and show a picture of what the word is. It doesn't sound too complicated, but we're suppose to have three different arrays, one for the english words, one for the translated words, and one for the pictures. And I just have no idea what to do. I don't understand how to check the textfield and make sure it has a value equal to that in one of the lists, I don't know how to associate the pictures to the correct words, I'm just completely lost and need a lot of help.

Here is my teachers exact words for the assignment, in case she explains it better than I do.
"Set up three one-dimensional arrays to contain the equivalent English and other-language-of-your-choice nouns, and the images of those objects.Typing a word in one of the languages and hitting the appropriate button should produce the translation and display the picture of that object. Make sure you check to see whether the word is in the dictionary. If it is not, display a message "Word is not found"."

I'm very new to Java as well, so I don't know a lot.

Comment: This is not a place for you to ask about your homework assignment. If you have code that you need help with, please edit the question. Check this page to see the questions you can post on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you explained you are new to Java, I think someone has to put you in the right track.

Needless to say, I won't provide you with code, which is very easy, because you need to learn to type your ideas into code.

Will give you a couple of ideas that all programmers use daily.

When you use arrays, they are like a set of blocks. What contain does blocks? essentially what you made the array of. In java, you can have an array of ints, or an array of Strings, and so on. They arrays are a set of the same data type.

In your activity you have to construct 3 structures (3 arrays). 
1. words in english (String)
2. words in the other language (String)
3. image linked to the word (Image?)

All the arrays work with indexes. Which enables you to spot what object from all the set you are trying to refer.

e.g.

An array of colours (which is an array of strings):
[ pink ] [yellow] [blue]
   0        1       2

The index, is the number of the place in your array, the n(th) element.
They usually start from 0 in most languages. Java starts from 0. This is an array of size 3. But the last element has an index of 2.
So if you need to do something with blue, you'll use number 2. If yellow, number 1, and so on.

Please refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for an explained tutorial on indexes and arrays.

Now, the key part in your assignment is to search if the words exists or not.
If the input is always in english then you need to search if the word exists in your english array (you can use for each , look that up in google), if its in the other language then look in such array.  The simplest way would be to search in all of the arrays until you hit the result, and retrieve the index.

You can set up your arrays to have the same meaningful word in the same order.

example (4 arrays, 3 languages, 1 for images)

[apple] [manzana] [pomme de terre]  [apple_image]
[grapefruit] [uva] [raisin]  [grapefruit_image]

If you know which index is the word that was typed (after searched for it), then you will just return the image in the place but from the array of images (with that index).

If the word is not found, then just print a message saying, is not in the dictionary. This can happen if you "iterate" your arrays and found no result.

Please try to set up a code and whatever language you want and then repost it here,  so we can take a look at your development.

Good luck. Programming is fun!, enjoy it!